# OWSTIMER detective work

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, owstimer

I'm curious if there is a way to look into OWSTIMER.

Let's say the timer service is using 10% CPU and 15 GB of memory.

Is there any way to see exactly what is running in the timer service?

I'm hoping for something like:

```
Outgoing mail-10%
Workflow1-12%
WorkflowService1-20%
```